# how can i write a function that takes in a list of restaurants as an argument and returns a list of only the restaurants that are not closed?

Tags: python, function, conditional-statements

```
fork_fig = {'categories': [{'alias': 'burgers', 'title': 'Burgers'},
  {'alias': 'sandwiches', 'title': 'Sandwiches'},
  {'alias': 'salad', 'title': 'Salad'}],
 'coordinates': {'latitude': 35.10871, 'longitude': -106.56739},
 'display_phone': '(505) 881-5293',
 'distance': 3571.724649307866,
 'id': 'fork-and-fig-albuquerque',
 'image_url': 'https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/_-DpXKfS3jv6DyA47g6Fxg/o.jpg',
 'is_closed': False,
 'location': {'address1': '6904 Menaul Blvd NE',
  'address2': 'Ste C',
  'address3': '',
  'city': 'Albuquerque',
  'country': 'US',
  'display_address': ['6904 Menaul Blvd NE', 'Ste C', 'Albuquerque, NM 87110'],
  'state': 'NM',
  'zip_code': '87110'},
 'name': 'Fork & Fig',
 'phone': '+15058815293',
 'price': '$$',
 'rating': 4.5,
 'review_count': 604}

frontier_restaurant = {'categories': [{'alias': 'mexican', 'title': 'Mexican'},
  {'alias': 'diners', 'title': 'Diners'},
  {'alias': 'tradamerican', 'title': 'American (Traditional)'}],
 'coordinates': {'latitude': 35.0808088832532, 'longitude': -106.619402244687},
 'display_phone': '(505) 266-0550',
 'distance': 4033.6583235266075,
 'id': 'frontier-restaurant-albuquerque-2',
 'image_url': 'https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/M9L2z6-G0NobuDJ6YTh6VA/o.jpg',
 'is_closed': True,
 'location': {'address1': '2400 Central Ave SE',
  'address2': '',
  'address3': '',
  'city': 'Albuquerque',
  'country': 'US',
  'display_address': ['2400 Central Ave SE', 'Albuquerque, NM 87106'],
  'state': 'NM',
  'zip_code': '87106'},
 'name': 'Frontier Restaurant',
 'phone': '+15052660550',
 'price': '$',
 'rating': 4.0,
 'review_count': 1369}
```

I have two restaurant list as above and i want to make function that returns a list of only the restaurants that are not closed by using conditional loops.

```
restaurants = [fork_fig, frontier_restaurant]

open_restaurants(restaurants)[0]['name'] ###I want restaurant name to be appear
```

Below is the code that I've been working on and cannot quite sure how I can fix this to get the value that I want to return.

```
def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    selected = []
    for i in restaurants:
        if fork_fig['is_closed']: 
            selected = restaurants[1]
        else:
            selected = restaurants[0]

    return selected
```

Comment: pass a dict to a function, iterate over it to get the value of the element `is_closed`, return accordingly.

Comment: For every restaurant you are checking if `` fork_fig['is_closed']: ``...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comment:

```
fork_fig = {'categories': [{'alias': 'burgers', 'title': 'Burgers'},
  {'alias': 'sandwiches', 'title': 'Sandwiches'},
  {'alias': 'salad', 'title': 'Salad'}],
 'coordinates': {'latitude': 35.10871, 'longitude': -106.56739},
 'display_phone': '(505) 881-5293',
 'distance': 3571.724649307866,
 'id': 'fork-and-fig-albuquerque',
 'image_url': 'https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/_-DpXKfS3jv6DyA47g6Fxg/o.jpg',
 'is_closed': False,
 'location': {'address1': '6904 Menaul Blvd NE',
  'address2': 'Ste C',
  'address3': '',
  'city': 'Albuquerque',
  'country': 'US',
  'display_address': ['6904 Menaul Blvd NE', 'Ste C', 'Albuquerque, NM 87110'],
  'state': 'NM',
  'zip_code': '87110'},
 'name': 'Fork & Fig',
 'phone': '+15058815293',
 'price': '$$',
 'rating': 4.5,
 'review_count': 604}

frontier_restaurant = {'categories': [{'alias': 'mexican', 'title': 'Mexican'},
  {'alias': 'diners', 'title': 'Diners'},
  {'alias': 'tradamerican', 'title': 'American (Traditional)'}],
 'coordinates': {'latitude': 35.0808088832532, 'longitude': -106.619402244687},
 'display_phone': '(505) 266-0550',
 'distance': 4033.6583235266075,
 'id': 'frontier-restaurant-albuquerque-2',
 'image_url': 'https://s3-media4.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/M9L2z6-G0NobuDJ6YTh6VA/o.jpg',
 'is_closed': True,
 'location': {'address1': '2400 Central Ave SE',
  'address2': '',
  'address3': '',
  'city': 'Albuquerque',
  'country': 'US',
  'display_address': ['2400 Central Ave SE', 'Albuquerque, NM 87106'],
  'state': 'NM',
  'zip_code': '87106'},
 'name': 'Frontier Restaurant',
 'phone': '+15052660550',
 'price': '$',
 'rating': 4.0,
 'review_count': 1369}


restaurants = [fork_fig, frontier_restaurant]  

def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    selected = []
    for i in restaurants:
        if 'is_closed' in i:
            if not i['is_closed']:
                selected.append(i['name'])
    return selected

print(open_restaurants(restaurants))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['Fork & Fig']
```

**Shorter-version**:

Using list-comprehension:

```
def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    return [x['name'] for x in restaurants if 'is_closed' in x and not x["is_closed"]]

print(open_restaurants(restaurants))
```

Using `get()` instead of indexing:

```
def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    return [x['name'] for x in restaurants if 'name' in x and not x.get('is_closed', True)]

print(open_restaurants(restaurants))
```

Comment: @JungmoKim you may accept the answer if it helped: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use the `filter` function:

```
def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    return filter(lambda r: not r['is_closed'], restaurants)
```

Comment: Now, It'd crash if there is no `is_closed` in a `dict`.

Comment: I'm making the reasonable assumption that all the dicts are structured the same way and contain all the required entries.

Comment: Indeed @Barmer, I take it back!

Answer (score 0):

Use List Comprehension here. Its one line and easy to read

```
open_restaurants = [restaurant.get("name") for restaurant in restaurants if not restaurant.get("is_closed")]

Output: ["Fork & Fig"]
```

Comment: It'd crash if there is no `is_closed` in a `dict`.

Comment: It'd crash if there is no "name" also. It's up to the developer if he knows key will be there or not always. As its True or False value for is_closed we can say it will be there. But yeah, we should handle it always. Added **obj.get()** Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to append all your open restaurants to a new list and print their names.
You will need two loops to accomplish this.

Here is how to do it:

```
restaurants = [fork_fig, frontier_restaurant] # a list of restaurants
def open_restaurants(restaurants):
    selected = [] 
    for i in restaurants:  # append all open restaurants to a new list
        if not i['is_closed']:
            selected.append(i)
    return selected

my_open_restaurants = open_restaurants(restaurants) # call the function

for rest in my_open_restaurants:  # print all the names
    print(rest['name'])
```

In your example the output will be: `Fork & Fig`

Comment: Why doesn't your second loop just use `for i in selected:`?